# Symfony 2 and Doctrine: log SQL query execution time

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to log SQL query execution time with queries? Currently only queries and their params are logged (into `doctrine.DEBUG` channel).

Symfony 2 (actually 2.0, cannot be updated) and Doctrine 2.2

Answer (score 1):

From a container aware object, such as your controllers or commands, you can enable logging like this.

```
$this
    ->get('doctrine')
    ->getConnection()
    ->getConfiguration()
    ->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());
```

This will set up [EchoSQLLogger](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.2/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Logging.EchoSQLLogger.html) to do your logging for you, which results in every query and its parameters being printed with echo and var_dump().

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't log the execution time which is what the questioner asked for.

Comment: Try with DebugStack as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773574/count-queries-to-database-in-doctrine2)