# Symfony2: How to add doctrine query execution time in .log

Tags: symfony, logging, doctrine-orm, execution-time

In Symfony2 logs SQL queries log in XXX.log by default. To check slow query i would like to have log query + its execution time as well.
I have created separate log file for doctrine log to do this i need following setting in my config.yml e.g

`monolog:
   handlers:
      doctrine:
            action_level: debug
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_doctrine.log
            channels: doctrine`

The doctrine query is logging in my given .log file but the execution time of each query is not there.
Please note: i want generic solution, so the logger will log my all queries + time

Comment: Take a look at this post maybe it helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380884/symfony-2-and-doctrine-log-sql-query-execution-time

Comment: Thank you, I have checked above given link that is for controller level. I am looking a generic solution, that means some setting  to log execution time too for whole project ( each and every controller page).

Comment: What about creating a listener to log  the execution of every controller after kernel response !! Im not sure about the way but im just thinking for a solution. Take a look at this article :
https://matt.drollette.com/2012/06/calling-a-method-before-every-controller-action-in-symfony2/

Comment: I am still trying but again a question is: a single controller  will have many methods and each method will have n of sql query (Doctrine)  to add listener on controller,  will work for each one ( please i am not expert in symfony2)?  My assumption will not be work though i am trying..

As per my investigation, monolog is writing the sql message in  the given .log file, i am trying to add excutionMS time with that message but i was not able to do it
even though i go in death and find http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.2/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Logging.DebugStack.html

Comment: Good logic.I think the solution is in the ORM layer (Doctrine2).Look at this bundle :  https://github.com/intaro/pinba-bundle