# How to log query execution time in Doctrine 3 using middlewares, now that "setSQLLogger()" is deprecated?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, middleware

Doctrine has deprecated its `->setSQLLogger()` in favour of Middleware.

I can't find any way to log start and end of query to get execution time.

Previously it could be done like in this question about [Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22382091/1346234).

What kind of Middleware should I create to be able to log execution time of a query?

Right now, I only have enabled logging, but that just logs the query *before* executing it.

---

I have found that all queries are being gathered inside `DebugDataHolder`, so as alternative it would be to log all queries at the end of request:

```php
use Doctrine\SqlFormatter\SqlFormatter;

class DatabaseFormatter implements FormatterInterface
{
    private string $id;
    private SqlFormatter $formatter;

    public function __construct(
        private DebugDataHolder $dataHolder,
    ) {
    }

    public function afterRequest() 
    {
        $queries = $this->dataHolder->getData();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470738/how-to-get-doctrine-to-log-queries-in-symfony2

Comment: No, I have this logging enabled, and as stated in question logs only query, but not execution times

Comment: Do you have a hook or something that is being executed before and one after the login? Because then you can implement the measurement logic.

Comment: How login flow can help count execution time of single query?

Comment: I'm not speaking about the login flow, but about the query execution flow

Comment: No, because Doctrine is making tons of queries internally.

Comment: It seems that Doctrine has `preExec` and `postExec` events: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/event-listeners.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have analysed how Symfony is adding its middleware and compiled following code that can do whatever is needed with queries:

First create basic middleware as stated in [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/DoctrineBundle/middlewares.html)

```php
namespace App\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver as DriverInterface;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Middleware as MiddlewareInterface;

class Middleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        /* ...dependencies from Symfony DI */
    ) {
    }

    public function wrap(DriverInterface $driver): Driver
    {
        // \App\Doctrine\Driver
        return new Driver($driver, /* ...dependencies */);
    }
}
```

Then add additional Middleware:

```php
namespace App\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver as DriverInterface;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Middleware\AbstractDriverMiddleware;

final class Driver extends AbstractDriverMiddleware
{
    public function __construct(
        DriverInterface $driver,
        /* ...dependencies */
    ) {
        parent::__construct($driver);
    }

    public function connect(array $params): Connection
    {
        // \App\Doctrine\Connection
        return new Connection(parent::connect($params), /* ...dependencies */);
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Doctrine;

use App\Log\Formatter\DatabaseFormatter;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection as ConnectionInterface;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Middleware\AbstractConnectionMiddleware;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Result;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Statement as StatementInterface;

class Connection extends AbstractConnectionMiddleware
{
    public function __construct(
        ConnectionInterface $connection,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($connection);
    }

    public function prepare(string $sql): StatementInterface
    {
        // \App\Doctrine\Driver
        return new Statement(parent::prepare($sql), $sql);
    }

    /*
     * Overwrite any method from parent class with features
     */
}
```

```php
namespace App\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Middleware\AbstractStatementMiddleware;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Statement as StatementInterface;

final class Statement extends AbstractStatementMiddleware
{
    private array $params = [];
    private array $types = [];

    public function __construct(
        StatementInterface $statement,
        private string $sql,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($statement);
    }

    /*
     * Overwrite any method from parent class with features.
     */
}
```

---

`Connection` class is used when making direct requests and `Statement` is used when making prepared statements.

Comment: this still doesn't answer your own question - how to measure query execution time.

Comment: @cheack it does (assuming measuring in old way was ok): Pass in Stopwatch instance, extend `execute` method in Middleware and add start and stop to stopwatch