# How to get all the queries executed by Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm creating a console command for my bundle with Symfony 2. This command execute several request to database (Mysql). In order to debug my command I need to know how much SQL query has been executed during the command execution. And if it's possible, show these requests (like the Symfony profiler do)

I have the same problem with AJAX requests. When I make an AJAX request, I can't know how much query have been executed during the request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enable the doctrine logging like :

```
$doctrine = $this->get('doctrine');
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();    
$em = $doctrine->getConnection();

// $doctrine->getManager() did not work for me 
// (resulted in $stack->queries being empty array)

$stack = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\DebugStack();
$em->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger($stack);

... // do some queries

var_dump($stack->queries);
```

You can go to see that : http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/logging-doctrine-queries-in-symfony2/

To return to Cesar what Cesar own. I find it here : [Count queries to database in Doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773574/count-queries-to-database-in-doctrine2)

Answer (score 0):

You can put all this logic into domain model and treat command only as an invoker. Then you can use the same domain model with controller using www and profiler to diagnose.

Second thing is that you should have integration test for this and you can verify execution time with this test.

Comment: "You can put all this logic into domain model" - can you share more details about this? Usually, database queries should **not** be part of the domain model, as this should not depend on the database directly